# php error using prepared statement I can't seem to find the error in this. the fields for user input and buttons disappear when i run it

Tags: php, prepared-statement

This throws an error where the page disappears, where shuold I fix it?

```
if ($valid) 
{
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE artist SET first_name=:first_name,last_name=:last_name WHERE artist_id=:id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute(array(':firstname'=>$first_name,':last_name'=>$lastname,':id'=>$id));

    Database::disconnect();

    header("Location: actor.php?actorId =".$id);
}
```

Comment: `:first_name` OR `:firstname` - You need to decide

Comment: Turn off the header location and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

After a `header()` call with a `Location:` keyword you should always place an `exit;` line otherwise the rest of the php script continues to execute. My guess is that is where the issue is. If I'm correct, the fix would simply be.

```
header("Location: actor.php?actorId =".$id);
exit;
```

**Edit:**
Ahh.. Also see the comment by Alon Eitan - that is possibly the real issue.